# Not able to access to Docker container through bound public ip

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I am trying to use docker containers on Bluemix but it looks like I am having troubles tried again this morning but seems it still does not work.
I have followed these steps:

- I have released all public ip issuing the cf ic ip release  command
- I have created a new container from the etherpad image (following the tutorial [Tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/docs/actionable-architecture-building-web-application-hosting-containers/)), requesting and binding a new public ip from the Bluemix GUI.
  Bluemix assigned 134.168.1.49 IP and bound it to the container.
  I expect the application to respond to http://134.168.1.49:9080/ but it hangs and responds me back with a connection timeout.
  Running a container from the same image locally works perfectly.
  Any idea, suggestion?

Comment: Hi, could you check about container config using ice inspect (container Id) ? It will show the configuration used, including IP address and ports

Answer (score 2):

There is a [known issue](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_troubleshoot.html#inbound_connectivity) with the IBM Containers service where there's a delay with the inbound network access being available after containers start. It can take up to five minutes for this to be available.

Are you able to successfully ping the bound IP address?

*Note: The IBM Containers service suffered a [major incident yesterday](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status) which affected operations. If you were trying to use it during this time, it may be related to that.*

Comment: I did it all over again today but the result is the same. The ip does not respond to ping.

Comment: Is the container shown as running in the UI or command line? Could you run the logs command during startup? It would be good to see if anything's error'ing out.

Answer (score 1):

We recently experienced some connectivity issues in our US-South datacenter. I would suggest redeploying your container with an IP address again today and determine if you have further success.

Comment: I have redeployed the container, bind it to a new public ip, but still i am not able to access it

Comment: When you create the container and select to add a public IP are you choosing at least one port to expose? We won't open the security group for ping unless you choose one port or more

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with Bluemix support, that was able to create a new image, start it up and access it successfully with my exact configuration. At this time, it appears there is something wrong with the networking for the tenant space where my containers are running. Bluemix team is investigating.
Thank you all for the support.